# How to filter rows with zero in some columns from the dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

In pandas, how do I filter out rows with value zero in certain columns?
I need to remove those rows, where all its values (except the first column) are zero.

Comment: Do you mean all values are zero in a row or column, your question is a little confusing

Comment: I meant all values are zero(except the first column) in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [70]:
# construct some dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':randn(5), 'b':[1,2,1,0,0], 'c':[0,0,0,0,0], 'd':[0,0,0,0,1]})
df
Out[70]:
          a  b  c  d
0 -1.125360  1  0  0
1 -0.485210  2  0  0
2 -1.461206  1  0  0
3 -0.121767  0  0  0
4  0.168165  0  0  1

In [82]:

# mask where values are not 0
mask = df[df.drop('a', axis=1) != 0]
mask
Out[82]:
    a   b   c   d
0 NaN   1 NaN NaN
1 NaN   2 NaN NaN
2 NaN   1 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN   1

In [94]:
# drop NaN values with a threshold of 1 valid value, and use the index to select those rows    
df.loc[mask.dropna(thresh=1).index]
Out[94]:
          a  b  c  d
0 -1.125360  1  0  0
1 -0.485210  2  0  0
2 -1.461206  1  0  0
4  0.168165  0  0  1
```